# Converting for loop to Excel

Tags: excel, algorithm

I am trying to make the equivalent to a for loop as an Excel usable entry.
I have a little experience coding, but none with Excel beyond the basic functions.

Scenario:  Looking for the total cost to buy N items.
Each item cost a fixed rate more than the previous item (15% for now).
I can get the cost of item N.
I want the cell to display the total cost to get all items up to and including N.

N = Total Number of items in list, this changes based on calculations elsewhere on the spreadsheet.

Rate = 15% or 0.15, but can change, so I don't want it hard coded.

This formula gives me the cost of Item N._____
((1/(1+Rate))*(((1+rate)^(N)))

I'm thinking something like the following would work, but I don't know how to write this is a way Excel can use.

```
Total = 0;
for(i=1,i=N,i++){
  Total = Total+((1/(1+Rate))*(((1+rate)^(i)));
};
```

This chart shows a manual calculation for what I want.

Item → Total Cost for N items

1. → 1.00
2. → 2.15
3. → 3.47
4. → 4.99
5. → 6.74
6. → 8.75
7. → 11.07
8. → 13.73
9. → 16.79
10. → 20.30

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide.

Gary

Comment: You don't need a loop.  There is a closed form for sums of geometric sequences. Each of your terms is `(1+Rate)^(N-1)` so the sum of the first N is `((1+Rate)^N)-1)/Rate`

Comment: Thanks Jerry,  This answer is exactly what I was trying to figure out, but I just didn't know the term "geometric sequence" to search for it.  Works like a charm and is easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

If A1 is "Rate" and A2 is "N" then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1/(1+A1))*((1+A1)^ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,A2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dirk for your answer.  I don't understand the "A1:Index" part so I'll have to look this up so I can try to use it later.

Comment: @GaryHullah `INDEX` returns a range (not a value). So for `INDEX(A:A,A2)` it will be column `A` and the row specified in A2 (in that case it is 14 so it will be A14). `SingleCell : SingleCell` is a range and this way it becomes the range from A1 to A14. Inside the `ROW` it becomes a simple array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}` which is used as the increasing `i`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with even though it is a little bit similar to Dirk Reichel's great answer.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1/(1+$B$2))*((1+$B$2)^ROW($A$1:A1)))
```

Basically I used `SUMPRODUCT` to sum up the total to the corresponding row.

[image]